# Throwing dice to determine a decision

Tags: halacha, sorcery-magic-kishuf

Say you have several options before you and they all seem equally good and you have no way of knowing which is the right option.

Is it allowed to throw dice after praying to hashem that he should show you the right option?

Is this included in "lo tenachashu" or would there be an opinion allowing it?